# How to override previous onClick css class change (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, class, jquery-animate, overriding

I wrote this code which animates (makes appear/disappear) a few elements on my page, including my 'work' div. It's triggered when clicking the link with class .fade

But I want that the others links of my menu, when clicked, override previous animation by making 'work' div fade away, then I can bring on & animate 'contact' div the way I did for the work div.

HTML part

```
    <div id="main">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>This is a second heading/h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="fade">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fade">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fade">three</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>

<div id="work">
</div>

<div id="contact">
</div>
```

jQuery part

```
$(function(){
  $(".fade").click(function(){
     $('#main').animate({ opacity: 1, top: "12%" }, 800);   
     $('h1, h2').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 800);     
     document.getElementById('work').style.cssText = "display: block";
     $('#work').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
     $('#work').animate({ opacity: 1, top: "350px" }, 800);
  });
});
```

Comment: Do the other menu items have a class?

Comment: In this example I have set class "fade" to all the links, but I don't know if it's necessary or not to make it work

Comment: You said there are other links that should hide the `work` DIV, I thought they were different from the `.fade` links.

Comment: The menu has 3 links, when I click the first one, the script I wrote ignite for the div "work". What I want is that when I click on my second menu link, or any other menu link, it overrides previous animation and start another animation for another div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute to each link saying which DIV it should animate, and add a class to all the target DIVs:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="fade" data-target="work">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fade" data-target="contact">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fade" data-target="something">three</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<div id="work" class="target">
</div>

<div id="contact" class="target">
</div>
```

In your jQuery, use that data as the DIV instead of hard-coding `#work`.

```
$(function(){
  $(".fade").click(function(){
     $('#main').animate({ opacity: 1, top: "12%" }, 800);   
     $('h1, h2').animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 800);
     var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
     $(".target:not("+target+")").hide();
     $(target).show();
     $(target).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 0);
     $(target).animate({ opacity: 1, top: "350px" }, 800);
  });
});
```

It looks like you're implementing tabbed browsing, maybe look at the jQuery UI Tab widget?

Comment: That works pretty great thank you. Sub question: Is there a way to set any duration/fade out when it overrides the previous div?